# How to convert this to LINQ

Tags: mysql, linq

I want to convert this query to LINQ.

```
select sup.firstname, sup.lastname, sup.bankaccountnumber, tbl.total  from  (select nfcids_id, sum(purchasecost) as total
from tbl_milkpurchases
group by nfcids_id)   tbl inner join tbl_nfcids nfc on tbl.nfcids_id = nfc.id inner join tbl_suppliers sup on nfc.suppliers_id = sup.id
```

Comment: You must have DBML attached to you VS project to use LINQ. Also when you have made changes to the DB you must update DBML - otherwise you can have unexpected errors.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query

```
var obj= from a in Context.tbl_milkpurchases.GroupBy(x=>x.nfcids_id).Select(x=>new{x.nfcids_id,total=Sum(x.purchasecost)})
                 from b in Context.tbl_nfcids.where(x=>x.id==a.nfcids_id)
                 from c in Context.tbl_suppliers.where(x=>x.id==b.suppliers_id)
                 Select new{c.firstname, c.lastname, c.bankaccountnumber, a.total}
```